# Simperium Received an Invalid Change

Tags: simperium

I am developing integration with Simperium, the integration is complete and has been running on test machines for sometime, I am starting to get this error on one of the devices and it keeps repeating constantly any ideas?

MeetingPad[891:1103] Simperium error (ActionLinks82), received an invalid change for (a18852011efe4964a6fdeb1853c790f3)
2013-02-07 10:07:05:277 MeetingPad[891:1103] Simperium client ios-7f43b434754d882923e966df5d885755 received change (ActionLinks82) ios-4176925448fa8ae0a2f1d0937627aa6b: {
    ccids =     (
        3f3b4550b23147d49e194038feea09a6
    );
    clientid = "ios-4176925448fa8ae0a2f1d0937627aa6b";
    cv = 5112df4b37a401031dcc5be1;
    ev = 2;
    id = 9ca0b7ad04314ab9888d75691be784b5;
    o = "-";
}

If this occured on a user account what would be the guidance?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is that you're using the latest version of the code. The repository was recently [open sourced on GitHub](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios). There used to be a bug related to nil values that could cause an invalid diff to appear in your change stream, but it should be fixed now.

Assuming you're using the latest code though, does the error repeat continuously for the same "id" value, or are there different values?

Looking at the Simperium code where this error occurs, it's possible it could be displayed if you've deleted an object locally and remotely at around the same time. In your app, might ActionLinks fit that pattern, i.e. are you creating and deleting a lot of them across multiple clients?

If that is indeed the cause, then the error is innocuous and we should patch the code. Let me know what you discover.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've been playing around with this error and thought I would give you some feedback. I used the latest release of the SDK and still had the same error.  I think it may be linked to the testing on the XCode simulator and swapping between different simulators (i.e. moving from 5.1 to 6.0 to 6.1)

Comment: OK, well let me know if you find out anything else. If you still see it happening in production on devices, it would help if you could [contact us](http://simperium.com/contact) and give us more details about your use case so we can think about it some more.